# Interpret string as coordinates in JavaScript using Regex

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to take a string that can look like either of the following:

- an aircraft carrier placed on A1, A2, A3, A4, A5; a battleship at B6, C6, D6; and a submarine at H3, I3, J3;
- A:A1-A5;B:B6-D6; S:H3-J3
- A(A1-A5); B(B6-D6); S(H3-J3);
- B(B6-D6);S(H3-J3);A(A1-A5)

I want to take the coordinates of each ship and place them on a 2D array. I understand how to use regular expressions, but I'm having trouble actually converting it into the coordinates that I can easily use to place. Any suggestions?

Comment: You almost certainly don't want a regex: if you parse coordinates with regex, you end up with unparsed coordinates and a regex bug. This is simple enough that splitting on the delimiters and then grabbing letter-number pairs ought to do it. If you want to go nuts, something like pegjs can write a full-blown parser.

Comment: You'd probably want to split it by `;` first and then look for `:` or if you know there's parentheses you can match for that. But that first string looks kinda messy...

Comment: How can I make it work for every single version of the string though?

Comment: If you are doing this for a battleship type of game you are implementing in javascript, why would you want to use this sort of string representation at all? What value do you get for EVER putting the ship locations into this sort of paradigm rahher than, for example a matrix representation?  You are going to spend time getting the data into that format and than back out again, without the format adding any value.

Comment: For example, why would a ship location representation not just be something like `var battleshipLocation = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]];`?

Comment: See, you don't want to make a game like this. It's like playing chess with strings formmated this way: "put the knight from A8 to B6

Comment: It's for a project, the 2D array is 10x10, goes from A-J rows and 1-10 columns. There doesn't seem to be a simple way to extract the data and regular expressions is pretty hit or miss to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly know what's the final format that you pretend. I just did a quick parsing just for fun. You can try to improve from here

```
function parseCoord(coord){
  return [coord[0].codePointAt() - 65, ~~coord[1]];
}

const yourString = "A:A1-A5;B:B6-D6; S:H3-J3"

const output = yourString
  .split(';')
  .map(x => x.match( /^\s?([BSA])[(:]?([A-Z]\d)-([A-Z]\d)\)?$/ ))
  .filter( x => !!x)
  .map( ([, type, ...coords]) => [type, ...coords.map(parseCoord)] )
  .reduce( (obj, [type, ...coords]) => Object.assign({ [type]: coords}, obj), {});
```

What do I get as output?

```
{ 
  S: [ [ 7, 3 ], [ 9, 3 ] ],
  B: [ [ 1, 6 ], [ 3, 6 ] ],
  A: [ [ 0, 1 ], [ 0, 5 ] ] 
}
```

I could improve from here but I really don't know what you need as a final result

If you want the 'A' to be 1 instead of zero just swap the 65 for a 64 in the `parseCoord` function.

You can also adjust the regex to take numbers above 9, instead of matching a single digit like this `/\d/`, you can match 1 digit and make the second one option by using the optional modifier `/\d\d?/`. So the matching group would like this `([A-Z]\d\d?)`

PS: Sorry if you are not used to ES6 syntax, I use it daily and I can't help myself.

EDIT: Regexes may look scary. Normally you have a problem, you solve it with a regex. Now you have two problems.

I will try explain the regex

`/^\s?([BSA])[(:]?([A-Z]\d)-([A-Z]\d)\)?$/`

`^` Start of the string

`\s?` There is a optional space

`([BSA])` Match the letter B, S or A and capture them

`[(:]?` There is a '(' or a ':' but it's optional

`([A-Z]\d)` Match a letter from A to Z followed by a digit and capture them

`-` Match a '-'. It's required because there is no '?'

`([A-Z]\d)` Match the other coordinate and capture it

`\)?` Match a ')' but it's optional

`$` end of the string

Hope that it was hopeful at certain extent.

Comment: The syntax is pretty weird to me, where exactly did the output that you provided get saved?

Comment: I was not saving it. Just edited the post and added an output variable called 'output'. You can test the code on a model browser or node.js version 6. If you use an older version you need to transpile the code using babel or any other ES6 transpiler